# Java - Improve method (try/catch)

Tags: java, methods, try-catch

I have a method for retrieving some coordinates from a very slow page.
My method works fine but i cant help to feel like it can be greatly improved, specially the try/catch clauses.

The method looks like this:

```
public void getCoordinates(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> loadingLabel.updateCoordinates(true));
        consolePanel.getConsole().append("\nRetrieving coordinates from server\n");
        shapes.clear();

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://TestServlet/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            consolePanel.getConsole().append(e.toString());
        }
        try {
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            try (InputStream dataSource = url.openStream()) {

                BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        dataSource, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
                double xCoordinate;
                double yCoordinate;
                String line;

                while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(!line.startsWith("#")) {
                        consolePanel.getConsole().append(line + "\n");
                        String[] text =  line.split(",");

                        xCoordinate = Double.parseDouble(text[0]);
                        yCoordinate = Double.parseDouble(text[1]);

                        xCoordinate = Math.abs(xCoordinate)/4;
                        yCoordinate = Math.abs(yCoordinate)/4;

                        String name = text[2];

                        shapes.add(this.mapPanelState.getNewShape(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 10, name));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            consolePanel.getConsole().append(e.toString());
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(this::repaint);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> loadingLabel.updateCoordinates(false));
    }
```

Any help to improve on it would be much appreciated.

Comment: one '*improvement*': if the URL is a `MalformedURL...` you will get a `NullPointerException` since `url = null` at `url.openConnection();`

Answer (score 1):

Your error handling is the same for both catch clauses. So you may easily merge those.

```
public void getCoordinates() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://TestServlet/");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        try (InputStream dataSource = url.openStream()) {
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataSource, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
            double xCoordinate;
            double yCoordinate;
            String line;
            
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                    consolePanel.getConsole().append(line + "\n");
                    String[] text = line.split(",");

                    xCoordinate = Double.parseDouble(text[0]);
                    yCoordinate = Double.parseDouble(text[1]);

                    xCoordinate = Math.abs(xCoordinate) / 4;
                    yCoordinate = Math.abs(yCoordinate) / 4;

                    String name = text[2];

                    shapes.add(this.mapPanelState.getNewShape(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 10, name));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        consolePanel.getConsole().append(e.toString());
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(this::repaint);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> loadingLabel.updateCoordinates(false));
}
```

Comment: You skipped closing `dataSource`. You can close in `finally` clause or go with `try-with-resource` option.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Act putting it in a try with resource like this try() ensures that it is closed when the loop is exited no matter what causes the exit so no dataSource.close() is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my improvement:

```java
        try {
                URL url = new URL("http://TestServlet/");

                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                try (InputStream dataSource = url.openStream()) {

                    BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            dataSource, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
                    
                    /*
                            your logic here
                     */
                }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //consolePanel.getConsole().append("URL is malformed! Try with a valid one");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //consolePanel.getConsole().append("....");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // runtime exceptions
        }
```

If your action does not change whether it's a `MalformedURLException`, `IOException` etc., the following catch block is enough:

```java
catch (Exception e) { 
       e.printStackTrace();
       //consolePanel.getConsole().append(e.toString());
}
```